# DIMM slot has gunk in it. Should I RMA the board?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I just bought a new ROG Crosshair VIII Hero motherboard and before I put in my ram into the A2 slot I noticed there was what looked to be some gunk in a few of the holes on the top of the DIMM slot. I tried pulling it off with tweezers but it looks like it's jammed in there. I examined the pins on the inside and they look to be clean. Can I still use this board or should I RMA it to be on the safe side?[image]

Comment: New motherboards shouldn’t look like that

Comment: You know what, I bet someone else RMA'd it and they put it back into stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, return it.

If that happened to it, what else happened to it?